# Angular JS not displaying in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know this question definitely get's asked a lot. But I honestly am not sure what I am doing wrong, and the solutions I have found haven't seemed to work.

For reference, I am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPxeCiy0RdY

Anyway. I am making a simple angular app that let's you input two values and it returns the result I have also included a small tester at the bottom of the HTML code to check and see if maybe I was having issues in my javascript file. I checked my references in the script tags already and made sure they were correct, all of the files are also in the same directory. I have built the controller, module, and referenced them in the HTML code. But for some reason, when I load my index page it simply does not recognize the Angular code parts. My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="app1">

<head>
  <title>Angular Practice Page</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Adds a controller that the Angular module will control.
    The view is the div element and all that it contains. The $scope
    component is used to provide data to the view. -->
<body>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <span>Calculate:</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="first" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="second" />

    <button ng-click="updateValue()">Sum</button>
    <br /><br />

    {{calculation}}

    <!-- Test Calculation -->
    <p>
      5 + 5 = {{5+5}}
    </p>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular Code:

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);

app1.controller('ctrl1', function($scope){
  $scope.first = 1;
  $scope.second = 1;

  $scope.updateValue = function() {
    $scope.calculation = $scope.first + ' + ' + $scope.second +
    ' = ' + ($scope.first + $scope.second);
  };
});
```

Image:

[image: The Angular is not being recognized.]

I've tried moving around the "ng-app" to different parts of the code in the HTML file and just poking around with no luck.

The tutorial teacher also has a completed set of code here: http://www.newthinktank.com/2016/02/angularjs-tutorial/ and even when I copied this verbatim it didn't work. Could it be something wrong on my computer? For reference I am using the Atom text editor and google chrome as my browser. I tested it with other browsers and got the same result.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First place to look is at what errors are thrown in browser console?

Comment: I think problem that you include <script src="script.js"></script> before angular.js library, put it after

Comment: Switch order of `script.js` and `angular` in the imports in head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place this script at the top of the head. Angular JS CDN should be at the top always before your any java script file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of this order,

```
<head>
  <title>Angular Practice Page</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Change the order of your script files to this. It would definitely work.

```
<head>
   <title>Angular Practice Page</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe that was the only mistake I was making. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Include Angular at the top. Since your script has reference to `angular` which is not loaded when your `script.js` executes.
2. Use input type `number` instead of text. Since, the `text` field give you string value which result in string concatenation instead of arithmetic operation.

```js
var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);

app1.controller('ctrl1', function($scope){
  $scope.first = 1;
  $scope.second = 1;

  $scope.updateValue = function() {
    $scope.calculation = $scope.first + ' + ' + $scope.second +
    ' = ' + ($scope.first + $scope.second);
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="app1">

<head>
  <title>Angular Practice Page</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Adds a controller that the Angular module will control.
    The view is the div element and all that it contains. The $scope
    component is used to provide data to the view. -->
<body>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <span>Calculate:</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="first" />
    <input type="number" ng-model="second" />

    <button ng-click="updateValue()">Sum</button>
    <br /><br />

    {{calculation}}

    <!-- Test Calculation -->
    <p>
      5 + 5 = {{5+5}}
    </p>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```